# gorm raw query Dynamic splicing conditions

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I use Gorm raw SQL query, but Web dev pass it on to me multiple parameters. If the parameter is empty, the query will not be performed. At present, I use map to splice the where statement, but it does not seem to work in raw mode。

```
where := make(map[string]interface{})
    if info.UserKey != "" {
        where["pay_merchant_order.merchant_fk"] = info.UserKey
    }
    if info.NickName != "" {
        where["sys_users.nick_name"] = info.NickName
    }
    if info.Type != 0 {
        where["pay_rate.id"] = info.Type
    }
    if info.IsSign != -1 && info.IsSign != 0 {
        where["pay_order.pay_status"] = info.IsSign
    }
    if info.PayOfficialOrder != "" {
        where["pay_order.pay_official_order"] = info.PayOfficialOrder
    }
    if info.Amount != 0 {
        where["pay_order.pay_amount"] = info.Amount
    }
    if info.MOrder != "" {
        where["pay_merchant_order.order"] = info.MOrder
    }
    if info.SOrder != "" {
        where["pay_merchant_order.sys_order_fk"] = info.SOrder
    }
    if info.Phone != "" {
        where["pay_channel_order.phone"] = info.Phone
    }
    if info.Rate != 0 {
        where["pay_order.pay_rate"] = info.Rate
    }
    db := global.GVA_DB.Debug()
    sql := "select pay_merchant_order.id,pay_merchant_order.order,pay_merchant_order.call_status,sys_users.username,pay_order.url,pay_merchant_order.merchant_fk,pay_order.token,pay_merchant_order.call_back,sys_users.nick_name,pay_order.pay_rate as rate,pay_order.pay_amount,pay_actualamount,pay_order.real_pay_amount,pay_order.pay_official_order,pay_order.pay_sys_order,pay_type.mode,pay_rate.name,pay_merchant_order.is_sign,pay_order.created_at,pay_order.pay_time,pay_order.overdue_time,pay_channel_order.phone from pay_merchant_order LEFT JOIN pay_order ON pay_order.pay_sys_order = pay_merchant_order.sys_order_fk LEFT JOIN sys_users ON sys_users.unique = pay_order.pay_merchant LEFT JOIN pay_channel ON pay_channel.id = pay_order.pay_channel_fk LEFT JOIN pay_rate ON pay_rate.id = pay_channel.rate_fk LEFT JOIN pay_payment_type ON pay_payment_type.id = pay_channel.channel_type_fk LEFT JOIN pay_type ON pay_type.id = pay_order.pay_type left join pay_channel_order on pay_channel_order.order_fk = pay_merchant_order.sys_order_fk"
    db.Raw(sql).Where(where).Group("pay_merchant_order.id").Order("pay_merchant_order.created_at desc").Scan(&payMerchantOrders)
    err = db.Count(&total).Error
    err = db.Limit(limit).Offset(offset).Error
```

Please tell me how to splice the query conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two solutions to try out:

**Solution 1 - without raw query**

```
//your code for additions to the where clause

...

//the main part of the query
db.Table("pay_merchant_order").
Joins("LEFT JOIN pay_order ON pay_order.pay_sys_order = pay_merchant_order.sys_order_fk").
Joins("LEFT JOIN sys_users ON sys_users.unique = pay_order.pay_merchant").
Joins("LEFT JOIN pay_channel ON pay_channel.id = pay_order.pay_channel_fk").
Joins("LEFT JOIN pay_rate ON pay_rate.id = pay_channel.rate_fk").
Joins("LEFT JOIN pay_payment_type ON pay_payment_type.id = pay_channel.channel_type_fk").
Joins("LEFT JOIN pay_type ON pay_type.id = pay_order.pay_type").
Joins("LEFT JOIN pay_channel_order on pay_channel_order.order_fk = pay_merchant_order.sys_order_fk").
Where(where).
Select("pay_merchant_order.id,pay_merchant_order.order,pay_merchant_order.call_status,sys_users.username,pay_order.url,pay_merchant_order.merchant_fk,pay_order.token,pay_merchant_order.call_back,sys_users.nick_name,pay_order.pay_rate as rate,pay_order.pay_amount,pay_actualamount,pay_order.real_pay_amount,pay_order.pay_official_order,pay_order.pay_sys_order,pay_type.mode,pay_rate.name,pay_merchant_order.is_sign,pay_order.created_at,pay_order.pay_time,pay_order.overdue_time,pay_channel_order.phone").
Group("pay_merchant_order.id").
Order("pay_merchant_order.created_at desc")
```

Then, you can use `Scan`, `Find`, and `Count` to retrieve the needed info.

**Solution 2 - only raw query**

This solution is based on preparing the where clause for the raw query and running only the raw query.

```
type WhereClause map[string]interface{}

func (wc WhereClause) ConvertToSQLString() string {
    list := []string{}

    for k, v := range wc {
        list = append(list, fmt.Sprintf("%s=%v", k, v))
    }

    return strings.Join(list, " AND ")
}

where := WhereClause{}
    if info.UserKey != "" {
        where["pay_merchant_order.merchant_fk"] = info.UserKey
    }
    if info.NickName != "" {
        where["sys_users.nick_name"] = info.NickName
    }
    if info.Type != 0 {
        where["pay_rate.id"] = info.Type
    }
    if info.IsSign != -1 && info.IsSign != 0 {
        where["pay_order.pay_status"] = info.IsSign
    }
    if info.PayOfficialOrder != "" {
        where["pay_order.pay_official_order"] = info.PayOfficialOrder
    }
    if info.Amount != 0 {
        where["pay_order.pay_amount"] = info.Amount
    }
    if info.MOrder != "" {
        where["pay_merchant_order.order"] = info.MOrder
    }
    if info.SOrder != "" {
        where["pay_merchant_order.sys_order_fk"] = info.SOrder
    }
    if info.Phone != "" {
        where["pay_channel_order.phone"] = info.Phone
    }
    if info.Rate != 0 {
        where["pay_order.pay_rate"] = info.Rate
    }
db := global.GVA_DB.Debug()
sql := fmt.Sprintf(`SELECT pay_merchant_order.id,pay_merchant_order.order,pay_merchant_order.call_status,sys_users.username,pay_order.url,pay_merchant_order.merchant_fk,pay_order.token,pay_merchant_order.call_back,sys_users.nick_name,pay_order.pay_rate as rate,pay_order.pay_amount,pay_actualamount,pay_order.real_pay_amount,pay_order.pay_official_order,pay_order.pay_sys_order,pay_type.mode,pay_rate.name,pay_merchant_order.is_sign,pay_order.created_at,pay_order.pay_time,pay_order.overdue_time,pay_channel_order.phone 
FROM pay_merchant_order LEFT JOIN pay_order ON pay_order.pay_sys_order = pay_merchant_order.sys_order_fk LEFT JOIN sys_users ON sys_users.unique = pay_order.pay_merchant LEFT JOIN pay_channel ON pay_channel.id = pay_order.pay_channel_fk LEFT JOIN pay_rate ON pay_rate.id = pay_channel.rate_fk LEFT JOIN pay_payment_type ON pay_payment_type.id = pay_channel.channel_type_fk LEFT JOIN pay_type ON pay_type.id = pay_order.pay_type left join pay_channel_order on pay_channel_order.order_fk = pay_merchant_order.sys_order_fk
WHERE %s
GROUP BY pay_merchant_order.id
ORDER BY pay_merchant_order.created_at DESC`, where.ConvertToSQLString())
    
db.Raw(sql).Scan(&payMerchantOrders)
```

Comment: but,my paging total is invalid